# If $1\le\lambda \le \kappa$ are cardinals, with $\kappa$ infinite and $\lambda<\text{cf}(\kappa)$, then every map $\lambda\to\kappa$ is bounded

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

I'm trying to prove the statement in the title, which is a step in the proof of a lemma in Kunen's *The Foundations of Mathematics*. Proceeding by contradiction, let $f:\lambda\to\kappa$ be unbounded, and put $X=\text{ran}(f)$. Since $\sup X=\kappa$, we have, by definition of cofinality
$$\lambda<\text{cf}(\kappa)\le \text{type}(X)$$
Now, since $\text{cf}(\kappa)$ is regular, it is a cardinal, and since $\lambda$ is also a cardinal, we deduce that $\lambda \prec \text{cf}(\kappa)$, i.e. there is no injection from $\lambda$ into $\kappa$. Then, since $f$ is a surjection from $\lambda$ onto $X$ (I'm assuming Choice throughout this whole question)
$$\lambda\prec \text{cf}(\kappa)\preceq\text{type}(X)\preceq \lambda$$
which is a contradiction (note the subtle change in typography from $<$ to $\prec$).

Is this argument correct? Is there any easier way to see it? Kunen does not have a tendency to make huge leaps, and while this isn't too difficult, he offers no justification, which is a tad strange.

EDIT: To clarify, $\text{type}(X)$ is the unique ordinal isomorphic to $(X,\in)$, and Kunen defines

$$\text{cf}(\kappa)=\min\{\text{type}(X): X \subset \kappa, \sup X =\kappa\}$$

Comment: Please add the precise definition of $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ as given by Kunen in this book. You should also clarify what $\operatorname{type}(X)$ means in this context. I'm assuming it's the order type of $(X; \in)$. (The reason I'm asking for this is that your claim follows immediately from the 'usual' definition of $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$.)

Comment: @Stefan I've added the pertinent definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument works, provided that all of the necessary machinery is in place; not having seen the book, I can’t judge that. I would argue a bit more explicitly:

By the definition of *cofinality* there is a set $C=\{\gamma_\xi:\xi<\operatorname{cf}\kappa\}$ such that $\sup C=\kappa$ and $\gamma_\xi<\gamma_{\xi+1}$ for each $\xi<\operatorname{cf}\kappa$. Since $\sup X=\kappa$, for each $\eta<\operatorname{cf}\kappa$ we can let

$$g(\eta)=\min\left\{\xi<\lambda:f(\xi)>\max\big\{\gamma_\eta,\sup\{g(\zeta)+1:\zeta<\eta\}\big\}\right\}\;.$$

Then $g$ is an injection (indeed, a strictly increasing function) from $\operatorname{cf}\kappa$ into $\lambda$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\lambda<\operatorname{cf}\kappa$.

Note that there’s no need for $\mathsf{AC}$ anywhere. This is the case in your argument as well, since both the domain and the range of $f$ come equipped with well-orders.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on why $g$ is strictly increasing? If $\zeta<\eta<\text{cf}\kappa$, then $f(g(\eta))>\gamma_\eta>\gamma_\zeta$, which gives $g(\eta)\ge g(\zeta)$, but I don't see why the last inequality must be strict.

Comment: @Reveillark: You’re quite right: I forgot to write down half of the definition of $g(\eta)$. I’ve added the condition that I had in mind but forgot to write.

Comment: Ah, got it now, thank you very much!

Comment: @Reveillark: You’re very welcome!